# Escaping angle brackets in Perl string

Tags: regex, perl

Seems like a really simple question but it's driving me wild. The answers I've found are far too complex.

I need to create a basic markdown script. I have a text file with this line:

```
# heading 1
```

I want to remove the "# " from the start so I use regex s/

```
$i =~ s/^#\s//;
```

Success! $i now reads

```
heading 1
```

The next step is to add html tags to make it a header. I need $i to be:

```
<h1>heading 1</h1>
```

Seems so simple

```
$i = <h1>$i</h1>;
```

nope...perl gets crazy about the use of <>. OK so escape them with single quotes..

```
$i = '<h1>'$i'</h1>';
```

Still nope. And I've been changing things and trolling answers for hours now to the point I'm more confused than when I started. Can someone please explain it like I'm 5 how the hell to make $i the string I need it to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to substitute inside a double-quoted string:

```
$i = "<h1>$i</h1>";
```

or use string concatenation:

```
$i = '<h1>' . $i . '</h1>';
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure I tried double quotes but there must have been other errors at the time. Got to love going in circles.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with a single replacement.

```
my $string = "# heading 1";
$string =~ s/^#\s*(.*)/<h1>$1<\/h1>/;
print $string."\n";
```

Comment: I would avoid doing `s???` since `m??` has special meaning and people might come to do that

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could also automatically deduce the heading level using the number of leading octothorpes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    next unless $line =~ /\A ([#]{1,6}) \s+ ([^\n]+) $/x;
    my $level = length $1;
    print "<h$level>$2</h$level>\n";
}


__DATA__

# heading 1
## heading 2
### heading 3
#### heading 4
##### heading 5
###### heading 6
```

Output:

```
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<h3>heading 3</h3>
<h4>heading 4</h4>
<h5>heading 5</h5>
<h6>heading 6</h6>
```

Answer (score -1):

Double quotes are working fine without error.
I tried this with following example

```
$i = "<h1>Here Comes The Header<\h1>";
print "$i";

output: 
<h1>Here Comes Header<h1>
```

I think there will not be any problem with double quotes